# Do I have to do something special for command objects to get instantiated in grails?

Tags: grails, groovy

I have a command object in another package from my controller. I import it in the controller. I create and return an instance of this command from the create action:

```
def create = {
    def reportCreateCommand = new ReportCreateCommand()
    reportCreateCommand.name = params.name
    reportCreateCommand.jrxmlFile = params.jrxmlFile
    return [cmd: reportCreateCommand]
}
```

But the save action closure doesn't instantiate an object of this command from the properties:

```
    def save = { ReportCreateCommand cmd ->
    if (cmd.validate()){
        def reportInstance = cmd.createReport()
        reportInstance.save()
        redirect(action:"show", id:reportInstance.id)
    } 
    else {
        render(view:"create", model:[cmd:cmd])
    }

}
```

Apparently cmd is null in the save closure. The command class has two properties name and jrxmlFile. From what I know grails should instantiate the command object in the save method from the params. Do I have to do anything else?

Comment: you should not be creating command objects http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GRAILS-5568, I would need to see more code to understand why your save action is failing; and including the code from the command object would help

Answer (score 2):

I believe calling `cmd.validate()` is unnecessary, you should just call `cmd.hasErrors()`. The command object will be validating by default on creation of the object

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is no validate() method on command objects. Just call hasErrors as suggestd by Aaron